# Js file loaded from server doesn't work, but loaded locally works

Tags: javascript, android, html, cdn

I have an Android webview app. 
I decided to move a js file online so that I can make changes that affect the app immediately without having to update the app.
If I load the script locally, everything works well.
If I load it from the server I placed it in, it doesn't.

Note: when I test the WebView app in my browser, everything works well.
On iOS works well either.
I only got problems on Android.

After a lot of searches, I figured out that internet permissions must be allowed in AndroidManifest file, and it is.
Javascript should be enabled, and it is.
I simply can't figure out what the problem is.
I also tried playing aroung with the html  tag and its attributes, but with no result.

Here is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mywebsite.com/content_controller/list.js"></script>
```

UPDATE: even an  file loaded from external server doesn't work, while loading it locally works.

Comment: Seems like a CORS related issue? But I not Android developer. However reading more about CORS may help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what is going on, but you might want to do the following.

1.) Did you forget to make http:// to https://
2.) add async to your script
3.) click on your link. Is the link correct. I can't go on it.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas!
1) The link works perfectly
2) I now tried adding async to my script, but no effect
3) The link in my post is not the good link, but in my app it is.